# Mysql multiple INSERT in a very little time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, innodb, sql-insert

In my project I have a javascript function that runs asynchronously a query that performs an insert into a MYSQL table (InnoDB) whenever the event onscroll occurs (after the event is stopped for at least 200 msec)

```
var delay = 200;
var timeout = null;
var fScroll = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        var ypage = window.pageYOffset;
        var sesId = responseSID.sesID;
        var pDest = $(location).attr('href');
        $.get( /php/regScroll.php", { P1: "E", P2: ypage, P3: sesId, P4: pDest } );
        fScroll = 0;
    },delay);
});
```

This event occurs many times over then, although the data that should be included are very small, the INSERT statement is called many many times per minute, and in the case of multiple concurrent users it is sometimes possible that the row is not inserted into the table.

Do you have some tips to manage INSERT into InnoDB tables very close together with MySql ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fix the syntax error.

Comment: Write it to a log file and process it in a cron every hour?

Comment: cache the query strings and run them all at once with cron job or after the session is finished. it depends when you need the inserts to be done :D

Comment: People tend to scroll quite a bit. It may be a good idea to cache the scrolling data on the client and then send it every couple seconds (or after a certain amount of data-points have been collected), as opposed to sending it as soon as the scrolling stops. This would ease the load on your server. Also, inserting stuff is not particularly expensive; making the script that inserts stuff very simple (using only vanilla PHP, and not some framework or similar) should enable you to call it a lot without slowing down the server too much.

Comment: Do you need a status of the execution of INSERT immediately ?
MySQL insert statement has an option DELAYED that's tell to mysql to not waiting for full sql execution before sending response to client http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

Comment: Thanks very mutch, i'm very interessed tocache the scrolling data on the client and then send it every couple seconds, but I have no idea what to write in my script to do this. could someone give me an example of code? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [INSERT DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html) if you don't need to query status for the rest of your JS script